# Margin-bottom won't move div in tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, margin

I'm trying to move the email component up the screen but margin-bottom won't do anything. Is there another tailwind utility I have to use?

```
import React from 'react'

function Email() {
  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center w-full items-center mb-8'>
<div className="mb-3 mx-auto xl:w-1/4 md:w-1/2 top-1/4 ">
            <input type="text" placeholder="example@email.com" className="p-3 rounded-l-md sm:w-2/3 font-['DM_Sans']" />
            <button type="button" className="p-3 bg-[#00ADC2] text-white font-semibold rounded-r-md sm:w-1/3  font-['DM_Sans']">Notify Me</button>
        </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Email
```

[How it looks on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLCSL.png)

Comment: Try removing top-1/4 class

Comment: You're better off just decreasing the bottom padding or bottom margin from the "infoinfofinfoinfo" element

Answer (score 1):

Margin bottom is going to push the content below down.

If you are looking to move the content up you can try negative margin on top.

With tailwind it's something like `-mt-8`.